# Rounding Decimals to 0, 5, 1

Tags: excel

Here in Kuwait (Arab country) we used three decimals after comma such as (100.523, 50.978, 340.143, 76.552, 414,081... etc).

How can rounding only the decimals to 0 or 5 or 1, for example:

```
1. 50.231 rounding to **50.230**  Keeping same
2. 50.232 rounding to **50.230**
3. 50.233 rounding to **50.230**
4. 50.234 rounding to **50.230**
5. 50.235 rounding to **50.235**  Keeping same
```

Another type of example for rounding to 1:

```
1. 50.236 rounding to **50.235**
2. 50.237 rounding to **50.235**
3. 50.238 rounding to **50.235**
4. 50.239 rounding to **50.235**
5. 50.240 rounding to **50.240**  Keeping same.
```

If it possible can solve this issue in excel by using a formula or no?

Comment: After properly formatting your question, it's a lot clearer what you want. Hence I deleted my incorrect answer and upvoted the right one.

Answer (score 2):

You seem do be doing a FLOOR operation, not a round. The difference is that floor always rounds downwards, to the precision decided, while ROUND rounds to the nearest, either up or down.

With excel, you can do the following and set the precision:

`=FLOOR(A1, 0.005)`

For reference, see https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/FLOOR-function-14bb497c-24f2-4e04-b327-b0b4de5a8886

If using ROUND, your examples

`3. 50.238 rounding to **50.235**
4. 50.239 rounding to **50.235**`

Would instead round to `50.240` since that is the nearest multiple of 0.005.

Comment: also `=FLOOR.MATH(A1, 0.005)` ;).

Comment: If number and significance have different signs, FLOOR returns the #NUM! error value.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld : From Excel 2010 and on, #NUM error happens only if number is positive and significance negative, but you can floor a negative number using a positive significance. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FLOOR-function-14bb497c-24f2-4e04-b327-b0b4de5a8886?CorrelationId=039d795d-d04f-4e0f-acea-24d8309a0821&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Thank you very much for help. But I want to round (50.236, 50.237, 50.238 & 50.239) to 50.240

Comment: @MR-77 Well, that's not the example you gave: 3. 50.238 rounding to **50.235**   But if that's what you need, use the ROUND function as someone has suggested.

Comment: @user985366  Thanks for that info.  I was not aware.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are rounding down to the nearest 0.005.  For that, try this formula, which gives the results you show in your example:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(A1/0.005,0)*0.005
```

Check that the formula also gives your desired results for negative numbers.
The FLOOR function would need to be modified to work for negative numbers in versions of Excel prior to 2010.

**EDIT:** In your **Comment** below, you have changed the results for Example 2.  It now appears that you want to perform a simple `ROUND`, unless the value is nn.nn5  (e.g. exactly on the .005 boundary).

It is not clear what level of precision you require for this, and the IEEE standard for double-precision floating point arithmetic allows for a bit of "slop".  So you will need to adjust the comparison exponent  depending on your desired level of precision.

Here are the results, showing both your original Examples in your **Question**, and the different set of Examples in your **Comment**:

[image]

Comment: From Excel 2010 and on, #NUM error happens only if number is positive and significance negative, but you can floor a negative number using a positive significance. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FLOOR-function-14bb497c-24f2-4e04-b327-b0b4de5a8886?CorrelationId=039d795d-d04f-4e0f-acea-24d8309a0821&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Thank you very much for help. But I want to round it in tow examples: Example 1: (50.231, 50.232, 50.233 & 50.234) to 50.230, Example 2: (50.236, 50.237, 50.238 & 50.239) to 50.240

Comment: @MR-77 Example 2 in your **Comment** here is very different from Example 2 in your **Question**.   What do you really want to do?

Comment: @user985366 Thanks for that info.  I will modify my answer. I was not aware that FLOOR had been improved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
=FLOOR.MATH(A1, 0.005)
```

or

```
=ROUNDDOWN(A1 * 200; 0) / 200
```